# Store this as an object

Tags: php, json, paypal

SOLUTION:
Each of the keys ending `:private` had a `__get()` and `toJSON()` method which is needed to get the data from them as _propMap is private.

I'm using PayPal's PHP API to take payments from PayPal, and the data I get after a payment has been completed, comes back as this

```
Array
(
[PayPal\Common\PPModel_propMap] => Array
    (
        [id] => PAY-THEID
        [create_time] => 2013-12-03T15:47:15Z
        [update_time] => 2013-12-03T15:47:34Z
        [state] => approved
        [intent] => sale
        [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object
            (
                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                    (
                        [payment_method] => paypal
                        [payer_info] => PayPal\Api\PayerInfo Object
                            (
                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [email] => my@email.com
                                        [first_name] => Tom
                                        [last_name] => Hart
                                        [payer_id] => thePayerId
                                        [shipping_address] => PayPal\Api\Address Object
                                            (
                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [line1] => 1 Main Terrace
                                                        [city] => Wolverhampton
                                                        [state] => West Midlands
                                                        [postal_code] => W12 4LQ
                                                        [country_code] => GB
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [transactions] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object
                                    (
                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                            (
                                                [total] => 0.33
                                                [currency] => GBP
                                                [details] => PayPal\Api\Details Object
                                                    (
                                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [subtotal] => 0.11
                                                                [tax] => 0.11
                                                                [shipping] => 0.11
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [description] => Payment description
                                [item_list] => PayPal\Api\ItemList Object
                                    (
                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                            (
                                                [items] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
                                                            (
                                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => Flowers
                                                                        [price] => 0.11
                                                                        [currency] => GBP
                                                                        [quantity] => 1
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [related_resources] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => PayPal\Api\RelatedResources Object
                                            (
                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [sale] => PayPal\Api\Sale Object
                                                            (
                                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [id] => 9L998852HN614082X
                                                                        [create_time] => 2013-12-03T15:47:15Z
                                                                        [update_time] => 2013-12-03T15:47:34Z
                                                                        [state] => completed
                                                                        [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [total] => 0.33
                                                                                        [currency] => GBP
                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                        [parent_payment] => PAY-4S184757A49956741KKO72AY
                                                                        [links] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/9L998852HN614082X
                                                                                                [rel] => self
                                                                                                [method] => GET
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [1] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/abc/refund
                                                                                                [rel] => refund
                                                                                                [method] => POST
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [2] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-abc
                                                                                                [rel] => parent_payment
                                                                                                [method] => GET
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [links] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/abc
                                [rel] => self
                                [method] => GET
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

I want to convert parts of that (shipping_address being one of them) to a json object (using `json_encode/decode()`, and store it in my database so in the admin section I can view the address so I know where to send things, however, I can't convert that to a json object, it just returns `{}`. How can I store these details in my database to view them later?

EDIT:

Json_encode code

```
$db['address'] = json_encode((array) $dets->payer->payer_info->shipping_address);
var_dump(json_last_error());
$db['payerId'] = $dets->payer->payer_info->payer_id;
$db['prices'] = json_encode((array) $dets->transations[0]->amount);
var_dump(json_last_error());
$db['description']  = $dets->transations[0]->description;
$db['items'] = json_encode((array) $dets->transations[0]->item_list->items);
var_dump(json_last_error());
$db['links'] = json_encode((array) $dets->related_resources[0]->sale->links);
var_dump(json_last_error());
```

The output of the $db array is

```
Array
(
[userId] => 10
[paymentId] => PAY-4VC71851RJ180032AKKPAB3Y
[state] => approved
[address] => {"\u0000PayPal\\Common\\PPModel\u0000_propMap":{"line1":"1 Main Terrace","city":"Wolverhampton","state":"West Midlands","postal_code":"W12 4LQ","country_code":"GB"}}
[payerId] => P77LD9M7MUQN2
[prices] => []
[description] => 
[items] => []
[links] => []
)
```

So some are getting encoded, some arnt.

Comment: How are you using `json_encode()`? Please show us the code.

Comment: Are you sure `json_encode()` is returning `{}`? And what does `var_dump(json_last_error());` output?

Comment: Updated the post again with the output of each encode I want to do. I tried dumping last error, each time it was `int(0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was also bothering me for a while and I struggled to find a straightforward answer. I'm  using the current PHP REST STK and in the sample ExecutePayment.php file saw something like this:

```
// Execute the payment
// (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);

echo "<html><body><pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre><a href='../index.html'>Back</a></body></html>";
```

As noted, the $result object is not very helpful to navigate. You can't directly encode the object as PayPal is doing some crazy stuff on their own in the SDK. As noted, the solution is to use the toJSON() method from the PPModal class to convert that object into JSON directly:

```
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);

$array = $result->toJSON();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

I hope that's a little clearer to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having with some values "not being encoded" is that some of your variable references are wrong.

For example, you are trying to encode:

```
$dets->transations[0]->amount
```

Whereas, I think you need to get that value from:

```
$dets->transactions[0]['_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private']['amount']
```

You have similar issue for most of your variable references.